# Preventing a page ending up in the sitemap based on a variable within a post - Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've got a large number of Jekyll pages/posts in my setup, and I need to prevent some of these
pages from being indexed by Google.

I'm using jekyll-sitemap that allows you to set "sitemap: false" in the frontmatter for a page to prevent it from being listed in the sitemap. However, since I have large number of pages doing this manually is not an option.

I've tried using jekyll-liquify to include a variable in the frontmatter of my pages, but I'm not able to put  `{{ sitemap_variable | liquify }}` in the frontmatter itself, for the sitemap plugin to evaluate.

jekyll-conrefifier seemed to have been able to do what I need, however that plugin does not support Jekyll 3.

Anyone have any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Do these posts have some element in common in the url? Maybe you could try with a [robots.txt](https://www.robotstxt.org/)

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing in common in the URLs :( The only way I really see this working is if there's a hack for me to get variables into frontmatter.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the easiest way for me here was to inject a noindex meta tag into the body of my post based on a Liquid condition. Although officially Google does not support this, unofficially it does take it into consideration even though it's not in the header.